# How to pass an image from a Chrome extension to a Python backend?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension that prevents images on a website from loading if they contain certain types of content.
I am having trouble passing the image in a format that allows it to be opened by the Python backend, which is supposed to analyze the image using a `fastai` model and return the prediction.
I have tried base64 encoding the image before passing it, passing it as a Form, as well as using a canvas, but nothing has worked.

Here is my latest attempt at the `javascript` function:

```
    function DoElement() {
        if (showAll)
            return;
        let el = this;
        if (isImg(el)) {
            //attach load event - needed 1) as we need to catch it after it is switched for the blankImg, 2) in case the img gets changed to something else later
            DoLoadEventListener(el, true);
            //see if not yet loaded
            if (!el.complete) {
                //hide, to avoid flash until load event is handled
                MarkWizmaged(el, true);
                DoHidden(el, true);
                return;
            }
            let elWidth = el.width, elHeight = el.height;
            if (el.src == blankImg && !el.srcset) { //was successfully replaced
                DoHidden(el, false);
            }
            else if ((elWidth == 0 || elWidth > _settings.maxSafe) && (elHeight == 0 || elHeight > _settings.maxSafe)) { //needs to be hidden - we need to catch 0 too, as sometimes images start off as zero
                DoMouseEventListeners(el, true);
                if (!el.wzmHasTitleAndSizeSetup) {
                    el.style.width = elWidth + 'px';
                    el.style.height = elHeight + 'px';
                    if (!el.title)
                        if (el.alt)
                            el.title = el.alt;
                        else {
                            el.src.match(/([-\w]+)(\.[\w]+)?$/i);
                            el.title = RegExp.$1;
                        }
                    el.wzmHasTitleAndSizeSetup = true;
                }
                DoHidden(el, true);
                DoImgSrc(el, true);
                DoWizmageBG(el, true);
                el.src = blankImg;
                
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.width = el.width;
                canvas.height = el.height;
                context.drawImage(el, 0, 0);
                var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, el.width, el.height);

                // Create a Blob object from the image data
                var blob = new Blob([imageData.data.buffer], { type: 'image/png' });

                // Create a FormData object and append the blob to it
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('image', blob, 'image.png');

                // Send the request to the server
                fetch('http://localhost:8000/predict', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData
                })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    if (data.prediction === 'nudity') {
                        MarkWizmaged(el, true);
                        DoHidden(el, true);
                    } else {
                        MarkWizmaged(el, false);
                        DoHidden(el, false);
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                });
```

Here is my `python` backend, which I am hosting locally:

```
from fastai.vision.all import *
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from starlette.responses import JSONResponse
import io
import base64

app = Starlette()
app.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware, allow_origins=['*'], allow_headers=['*'], allow_methods=['*'])

# Load the trained model
learn = load_learner('/Users/.../Documents/Personal/WorkSafe/Backend/resnet18.pkl')

# Define the prediction route
@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
async def predict(request):
    data = await request.form()
    image = data.get("image", None)

    if image is not None:
        # Retrieve the file data from the form
        image_data = await image.read()
        
        # Reset the stream position to the beginning
        image_data.seek(0)

        img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
        img = img.convert('RGB')
        # Make the prediction
        prediction, _, _ = learn.predict(img)
        
        return JSONResponse({'prediction': str(prediction)})
```

When I run this, it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shaulsaitowitz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 428, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "/Users/shaulsaitowitz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/shaulsaitowitz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/shaulsaitowitz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/Users/shaulsaitowitz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/Users/shaulsaitowitz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 91, in __call__
    await self.simple_response(scope, receive, send, request_headers=headers)
  File "/Users/shaulsaitowitz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 146, in simple_response
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/shaulsaitowitz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 62, in __call__
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/shaulsaitowitz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 57, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "/Users/shaulsaitowitz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 46, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/Users/shaulsaitowitz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 727, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/shaulsaitowitz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 285, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/shaulsaitowitz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 74, in app
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/shaulsaitowitz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 57, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "/Users/shaulsaitowitz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 46, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/Users/shaulsaitowitz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 69, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/Users/shaulsaitowitz/Documents/Personal/WorkSafe/Backend/worksafe_app.py", line 27, in predict
    image_data.seek(0)
```

I had just added `.seek(0)` at the suggestion of another answer to fix the following error, which I got previously:

```
    response = await func(request)
  File "/Users/shaulsaitowitz/Documents/Personal/WorkSafe/Backend/worksafe_app.py", line 26, in predict
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
  File "/Users/shaulsaitowitz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2967, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fdff4b43ef0>
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? (I find it difficult to provide a Minimal Reproducible Example because running it would require recreating a Chrome extension for demonstration.)

These questions were suggested as similar but are actually not helpful for how to pass an image:
[passing an image from background page to content script javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492296/passing-an-image-from-background-page-to-content-script-javascript)
[Message passing to chrome extension from local python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61252039/message-passing-to-chrome-extension-from-local-python)

Edit: My question was marked as a duplicate of How to make a cross-origin request in a content script (currently blocked by CORB despite the correct CORS headers)?, however they are unrelated. That question pertains to not being able to receive a response, whereas I am asking how to post a request in a way that can be handled by the backend.

Comment: does the backend work with postman (https://www.postman.com/) or any web api testing tool?

Comment: not sure @Qori . I've never used a web api testing tool. beginner here...